# React Route Protection Fail because of the state did not change

Tags: reactjs, async-await, state

I am trying to implement a route protection feature calling a backend for authentication. backend response is ok, but the front end gives me a strange behaviour, I stucked for a week but didn't find the problem.

In the code, the ok state always give me false value, I assume it's because of the async code.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Outlet, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

function RequireAuth() {
    const [ok, setOk] = useState(false);
    const fetchUser = async () => {
        try {
            const { data } = await axios.get('http://localhost:5555/api/current-user', {
                withCredentials: true,
                credentials: 'include',
            });
            console.log(data);
            //data.ok === true
            if (data.ok) {
                setOk(true);
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchUser();
    }, []);
    console.log(ok);
    // ok === false
    return ok ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/login" />;
}

export default RequireAuth;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your component RequireAuth mounts, it immediately returns the JSX based on the initial state of ok, which is false. This means your component will attempt to navigate to /login before the fetchUser async function has a chance to update the state

how about add a loader and only check the navigation after fetch is complete

```
 const [ok, setOk] = useState(false);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true); // Added loading state

    const fetchUser = async () => {
        try {
            const { data } = await axios.get('http://localhost:5555/api/current-user', {
                withCredentials: true,
                credentials: 'include',
            });
            if (data.ok) {
                setOk(true);
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } finally {
            setLoading(false); 
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchUser();
    }, []);

    if (loading) {
        return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }

    return ok ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/login" />;
}
```